# update timestamp trigger not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

Iam trying to create a trigger on a particular field of a table.Each time the value of that column changes the timestamp should get recorded in the timestamp column field which is ticket_close_time (data tytpe timestamp).But every time i try to execute the trigger i get an error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6"
I just dont understand what the issue is.I have tried now(),current_timestamp but nothing works i just keep getting the error.

TRIGGER CODE

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON ticket_tran
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
        IF NEW.ticket_resolved_flag <> OLD.ticket_resolved_flag THEN
           SET NEW.ticket_close_time = now();     
        END IF;
     END
   //
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this with a trigger, mysql has something native for that `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

As for your trigger: i can't spot a syntax error. I think the problem is that the delimiter is still set to ; Make sure that you have set the delimiter to something other then ; before executing the CREATE TRIGGER statement. You can do this by executing this command:

`DELIMITER //`

Comment: on update works for all the columns i just want on update to run for a particular column.Iam really sorry for bad editing but i do have delimiters in my code